# Mouse over in blocks of products (cards) with CSS scale + show a button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, position, scale

I want to display a list of products and with mouse over show a "Buy" button.

The cards have a link to "Buy" and the rest of the link block to the product page. (Check out the HTML).

The animation for the cards will be with scale CSS, however when I show the button there is a break in the blocks in CSS.

I'm using Bootstrap.

Thank you!

CSS:

```
ul li {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  transition: all 100ms linear;
  float:left;
}
ul li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 100ms linear;
  z-index:999;
}
```

JS:

```
$('ul li').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find(".btn").fadeIn(100).css("display", "block");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find(".btn").fadeOut(100).css("display", "none");
  }
);
```

---

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RYOd.png)

[View CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWVqMa)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `Html`. bootstrap is 12 column base. Means one row contain 12 column. But you use 18.you need to change your html like bellow:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul>
      <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/255x200">
        </a>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h4>Product name</h4>
            <span>$220,90</span>
            <span class="off"><b>$199,90</b></span>
            <span class="info">by credit card</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </li>
        <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/255x200">
        </a>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h4>Product name</h4>
            <span>$220,90</span>
            <span class="off"><b>$199,90</b></span>
            <span class="info">by credit card</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </li>
        <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/255x200">
        </a>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h4>Product name</h4>
            <span>$220,90</span>
            <span class="off"><b>$199,90</b></span>
            <span class="info">by credit card</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </li>
         <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/255x200">
        </a>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h4>Product name</h4>
            <span>$220,90</span>
            <span class="off"><b>$199,90</b></span>
            <span class="info">by credit card</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </li>
       </ul>
       <ul>
        <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/255x200">
        </a>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h4>Product name</h4>
            <span>$220,90</span>
            <span class="off"><b>$199,90</b></span>
            <span class="info">by credit card</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </li>
         <li class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/255x200">
        </a>
        <div>
          <a href="#">
            <h4>Product name</h4>
            <span>$220,90</span>
            <span class="off"><b>$199,90</b></span>
            <span class="info">by credit card</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can display with transition(height) to div before btn?

Comment: @RhianMolinari sorry i can't understand. can you please describe in details what you want/

Comment: @RhianMolinari you can get help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420962/button-css-transition-does-not-work-inside-a-div

Answer (score 0):

**Do Like this example.....**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").hover(function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "green");
            }, function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p>Hover the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

For More https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/